# How to make my notebook up

Tags: boot, operating-systems, anti-virus, updates, laptop

After i update my anti-virus s/w, my notebook can't reboot normally, what happened? It just sitting on the welcome screen, displaying it is loading some configuration.
Somebody please help me, i don't want to reinstall/restore my OS. Appreciate anyone's help!

Comment: Can you give us any info on the OS and AV?

Comment: It's Windows XP 32bit and Avast free version

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a modern version of Windows (likely since you mention antivirus software), boot into Safe Mode by restarting and repeatedly pressing F8 during startup.  From Safe Mode, follow [Microsoft's instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/helpandsupport/learnmore/systemrestore.mspx) to restore a previous system state:

1. Click Start.
2. Point to All Programs.
3. Point to Accessories.
4. Point to System Tools.
5. Click System Restore.
6. Follow the instructions on the wizard.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, nut i don't want to lose anything, In addition, my restore is not work.

Comment: If you have Windows disks, try a repair install.  This will replace Windows files without uninstalling applications or deleting data.

Answer (score -1):

Try booting from the safe mode. Once there, uninstall your anti virus program. [change your anti virus !]. The update most probably has corrupted a file in the start up menu thus not allowing a full boot up.

This can can also be done from the command line but I am not sure of the correct programming so i cannot go further on that. If this fails try flashing the system thus making the notebook reset to factory settings etc but still retaining all programs.

Comment: flashing ?

Comment: Hi, i just tried uninstall, it works!

Comment: It's Windows XP 32bit and Avast free version